# Loadamount() and loadtotalvalue() wont load when I load the website

Tags: javascript

I need help. The problem is that loadsumerg is successfully loaded, while loadamounts and loadtotalvalue return no results, even though the values are stored in Local Storage. I have already tried changing the order of the load functions and placing them both inside and below the render function. My question is: Why is the stored content not being displayed, while loadsumerg is working fine?

```
let menus = ['Pizza', 'nizza', 'rizza','salat','aa','ddd'];
let prices = [5.0, 3.0, 2.5, 4.0 , 7.0 ,9.0];
let index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let amounts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
// Initiale Anzahl auf 0 setzen
let imgs = ['/htmimg/pizza.jpg', '/htmimg/noodle.jpg'];
let sum = 0;
let newid = ['Pizzen', 'Nudeln'];
let totalvalue = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
let newsum = 0;
let dd;
let order = new Set();


loadamounts();
loadtotalvalue();

function render() {
   

    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += `
        <div class="defgap" id="def${i}"><div> `;
        if(i == 0){
            document.getElementById(`def${i}`).innerHTML +=`
            <img class="changeh" src="${imgs[i]}" alt="" srcset="">
            ${newid[i]}
            `;
        }
        else if(i == 3){
            document.getElementById(`def${i}`).innerHTML += `
            <img class="changeh" src="${imgs[1]}" alt="" srcset="">
            ${newid[1]}
            `;
        }
        document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += `
       
          <div class="asas">
                <div id="cc${i}">${menus[i]}</div>
                <div class="pfm" id="dd${i}">${prices[i]} €</div>
            <p onclick="addToBasket(${i})">Hinz.</p>
          </div>
        `;
      
    }

    document.getElementById('newmen').innerHTML = '';
    newsum = 0;
    let warenkorb = document.getElementById('fdw');
    
    for (let j of order) {
        if (amounts[j] > 0) {
            totalvalue[j] = amounts[j] * prices[j];
            document.getElementById('newmen').innerHTML += `
                <div>${menus[j]}</div>
                <div id="amounto${j}">Anzahl: ${amounts[j]}</div>
                <div id="totalo${j}">Gesamtpreis: ${totalvalue[j]} Euro</div>
                <div id="del${j}" onclick="setamountdown(${j})">delete</div>
            `;
        }
    } 
    
    document.getElementById('newerg').innerHTML = `<div>Gesamtsumme: ${sum} Euro</div>
<button onclick="deleverything()">Löschen</button> 
<button onclick="issumgreater()">Kaufen</button>`;

    if(sum > 0){
        dd = warenkorb.classList.add('dn');
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('newerg').innerHTML = ``;
        dd = warenkorb.classList.remove('dn');
    }    
    saveamount();
    savetotalvalue();
    sumerg();
    
}

loadsumerg();

// amounts muss runtergestezt werden

function issumgreater(){
    if (sum < 10) {
        alert('Die bestellung muss den Mindestbetrag von 10 euronen erfüllen');
    }
}

function addToBasket(index) {
    amounts[index]++;
    sum += prices[index];
    order.add(index);
    render();
}

function setamountdown(index){
    amounts[index]--;
    sum -= prices[index];
    render();
}

function deleverything(){
    amounts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    sum = 0;
    render();
}

// Save and Load im LocalStorage

function saveamount(){
    let dd = JSON.stringify(amounts);
    localStorage.setItem('Anzahl', dd);
}

function loadamounts(){
    let dd = localStorage.getItem('Anzahl');
    if(dd){
      amounts = JSON.parse(dd);
    }
   
    }

function savetotalvalue(){
    let og = JSON.stringify(totalvalue);
    localStorage.setItem('TotalerWert', og)
}

function loadtotalvalue(){
    let og = localStorage.getItem('TotalerWert');
    if(og){
        totalvalue = JSON.parse(og);
    }
}

function sumerg(){
    let dj = JSON.stringify(sum);
    localStorage.setItem('TotaleSumme', dj);
}

function loadsumerg(){
  
    let dj = localStorage.getItem('TotaleSumme');
    if(dj){
        sum = JSON.parse(dj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to test if variables `totalvalue` and `amounts` are really empty or its just a problem with the `render()` function?

Comment: totalvalue and amounts dont semed empty because the values of these are stored in Local value and they are shown when you dont load the site new